# How to get deleted transaction form from netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I accidentally deleted one transaction form(Primary Inventory Adjustment),is it possible to get it back ??

If not how to create another form please help me

Comment: You cannot get the old deleted transaction. :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Customizations > Forms > Transaction Forms

It will list all transaction form. If you need to create a custom one click 'Customize' link in one of the standard form and you can now add fields, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get back a deleted record, unless you have a sandbox environment with a copy.

To create a new form do as eliseobeltran sald.